# jQuery File Download plugin issue with Spring Security CSRF token

Tags: jquery, file, spring-security, download, csrf

I am using jQuery File Download plugin and for back-end I am using Spring with Spring Security and when I am trying to send a request back to the browser to download a file I get a 403 error:

> HTTP Status 403 - Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.

I am trying to pass this parameter as request header, how is this possible into this plugin?

For example in a simple AJAX request I have done this by write:

```
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
$.ajax({dataType : 'json',
        url : serverURL,
        data : filesData,
        type : fetchMethod,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false,
        contentType:false,
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
            xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);

        }
})
```

and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass '_csrf' parameter as below

```
$.fileDownload(url, {
    data: {
        '_csrf': <CSRF-TOKEN>
    },
    successCallback: function (html,data) {
     },
     failCallback: function (form,data) {
     }
});
```